# Qt6 Cmake configuration not found

Tags: macos, cmake, build, configuration, qt6

I am a newbie at Qt. I am not able to build the examples provided by Qt, because I get the following message in every example I try:

```
Make Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt6.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt6" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt6Config.cmake
    qt6-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt6" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt6_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt6" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

followed by

```
CMake process exited with code 1
```

and finally

```
No CMake configuration found!
```

I recently installed Qt 6.4.3 on MacOS Ventura 13.1, then launched several examples using Qt Creator. All of what I tested fail on the same error. Among the others, the "quickcontrols2/gallery", the error is on CMakeLists.txt line 12.

The line 12 is:
`find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Quick QuickControls2)`

In Qt Creator, Project > Build settings > Initial configuration [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY1cO.png), I see several CMake variables, among which CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH suggested in other posts. But there is nothing in the Current configuration.

I think that I missed something very obvious, but can't figure out what. I also think that the error message gives me clues, but I don't understand them because CMake and Qt are new to me. Could you drive me to the appropriate documentation or explanation?

Comment: Not sure about the installation on macos, but on windows there's a compiler/qt-version-specific subdirectory in the qt install dir that needs to be passed either as part of the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` list or via `Qt6_ROOT` variable (cache or environment vars should work): `<Qt install location>/6.4.1/msvc2019_64`. In this location there should be a file `lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake`. Note: you could also pass the `--debug-find` command line option during configuration to make CMake list all the paths it checked for the cmake configuration script of Qt6.

Comment: Thanks, fabian. Yes, on MacOS there is also a `<Qt install location>/<Qt version>/macos/lib/cmake/Qt6` directory. The variable is `Qt6_DIR`, actually, and I do not find it in the project current configuration (there are no variables in it).

Answer (score 0):

Found a cause, and a solution.
In the kit manager, the default kit for desktop appears as "Manual" (instead of "Automatically detected"), and the Qt version was set to "None". Strange.
After setting the version to "Qt 6.4.3 for macOS", I could easily reconfigure the project... and that worked!